# The structure of the sentence is strange, but it has been written in the book

Tags: grammar

> In this book, by "the state" we mean whatever information is available to the agent.

Hmm....... I've never learned about this sentence structure.
Is the above sentence equivalent to the following sentence?

> In this book, "the state" means any information available to the agent.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything special about that sentence structure. What exactly is confusing you?

Comment: "We" refers to the author(s). That is how they use the term _the state_ in this book.

Comment: @DanielRoseman It's weird in that the sentence is starting with the phrase, by "the state". Is it common?? If so, is "By 'term' we mean 'description' equal to "we mean 'description' by 'term'? For example, "I mean a beast similar to a hairy man by a gorilla" is equal to "By gorilla, I mean a beast similar to a hairy man"?

Comment: @Danny_Kim  If I understand you correctly, yes, **By X, we mean Y** is the same as **We mean Y when we say X**.  But it is only idiomatic in that order, so your example *I mean a beast similar to a hairy man by a gorilla* looks very strange.

Comment: @stangdon Ahah~ As a result, I have to say "By gorilla, I mean a beast similar to a hairy man." or "I mean a beast similar to a hairy man when I say a gorilla." Right? Thank you!!!!! very much

Comment: @Danny_Kim Yes, that's correct!